# Why is an empty string returned from hanzi.to_pinyin()?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ipython

http://dragonmapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/readme.html

I'm trying to use dragonmapper to convert characters to pinyin, and I'm trying the tutorial but I'm stuck.
http://dragonmapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

```
from dragonmapper import hanzi
s = '这个字怎么念？' 
pinyin = hanzi.to_pinyin(s)
```

At this point `pinyin` is an empty string `u''`.  What am I doing wrong?

(also asked here: https://github.com/tsroten/dragonmapper/issues/11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I forgot to mark the string as unicode:

`s = u'这个字怎么念？'`

alternatively, make strings unicode:

`from __future__ import unicode_literals`